# Adamek's Closure under Limits and "Strict" Closure under Products and Equalizers

Tags: category-theory

In my previous post, that you can find here

[Reflective Subcategories, Limit closedness and Repleteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475223/reflective-subcategories-limit-closedness-and-repleteness/4475496#4475496)

I asked for some clarification regarding a result of Adamek's "The Joy of Cats" concerning the relationship between the closure under limits of reflective subcategory and repleteness. I received a really excellent answer, which I recommend everyone to read, because it clarifies the core of the matter in a very simple way and insists that Adamek, in fact, gives a more "strict" version of the notion of "creation of limits" than to that usually known in the literature.

However, at this point, I have a question:

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a complete category and $\mathcal{A}$ a full reflective subcategory. Assume that for any pair of morphisms f,g in $\mathcal{B}$ the equalizer computed in $\mathcal{B}$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$. Same thing for products of small sets of objects in $\mathcal{A}$. In other terms, $\mathcal{A}$ is "strictly" (in the sense of answer to the previous post) closed under equalizers and products, if I well understand the sense of the term "strict" in that answer. So, is it true that the "strict" closure under equalizers and products implies the limit-closedness in the sense of Adamek?

The above result, which would be fundamental in theory (like the fact that completeness may be checked through the existence of equalizers and products), is not proved in Adamek's book. This makes me doubt the veracity of the result, since its relevance would certainly have meant that it deserved to be included in the book. However, if you read my previous post, in the weak sense the corresponding result holds. Is it possible to have information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any isomorphism $Y\cong X$ is the limiting cone over the category consisting of the single object $X$ and its identity morphism. Theorem 12.3 (which asserts that any limit can be constructed out of products and equalizers) shows that it is also the equalizer of the pair of identity morphisms $\mathrm{id}_X\colon X\rightrightarrows X$. Consequently, if the subcategory $A$ is strictly closed under equalizers, then it is isomorphism-closed.

You can now use Theorem 13.27 to conclude that if a full reflective subcategory is strictly closed under equalizers, then it is strictly limit-closed.